# How to pass Longitude and Latitude to google map direcive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

I am working on AngularJS. I am trying to display a Google Map, based on selected Longitude and Latitude. so i have followed the following steps,

1, Included Google Map Script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2, Written an angularJS directive for Google Map

```
.directive('map', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var markersArray = [];
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.glat,attrs.glang),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), myOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    addMarker({
                    lat: e.latLng.lat(),
                    lng: e.latLng.lng()
                  }); 

                    console.log(e);
                });

            }); // end click listener

            addMarker= function(pos){
            for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray.length = 0;
               //map.clearOverlays();
                //alert(pos.lat);alert(pos.lng);
               var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat,pos.lng);
               marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng, 
                    map: map,
                    title:"Hello World!"
                });
                scope.pinLatLang={"lat":pos.lat,"lang":pos.lng};
                scope.$apply();
                markersArray.push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){});
            } //end addMarker
        }
    };
})
```

3, Written following markup,

```
<map id="map_canvas" glat="33.6408" glang="-84.4457" class="col-md-10"></map>
```

when i did like above it works fine. But in my scenario i need to call a web service and get longitude and latitude like,

```
 $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: "myUrl" + $routeParams.param1,

                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  //Here i will set scope variables
    $scope.GLongitude=data.Longitude;
    $scope.GLatitude=data.Latitude;
    });
```

and using those scope variables in my directive element markup like

```
 <map id="map_canvas" glat="{{GLongitude}}" glang="{{GLatitude}}" class="col-md-10"></map>
```

but it is not loading map, i think scope variables not yet gets initialized when directive create markup. How can i achieve this. Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Google Maps for AngularJS](http://angular-google-maps.org/) - an AngularJS directives to integrate Google Maps into your applications.

There are directives for most of the widely-used Google Maps objects, including markers, windows, lines and shapes.

**Example:**

```
<google-map center='{expression}' 
zoom='{expression}'
draggable='{string}'
dragging='{expression}'
refresh='{expression}'
options='{expression}'
events='{expression}'
bounds='{expression}'>

<!-- other directives here -->
</google-map>
```